# Spelling Bee Bee Bee

Tags: word, knowledge, language, english

I once attended an English-language spelling bee where a speller, during her turn, repeated the same letter three times in a row, and she was judged to be correct. She spelled the word perfectly, without restarting, and without stuttering. In fact, none of the words from that day’s spelling bee had any of the same letter three times in a row. What was the word? There are two possible answers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming the contestants respond by stating the word, spelling the word, and then stating the word again:

> The contestant was asked to spell either the word "I" or "a", to which the correct response would be simply stating the letter three times in a row.

Comment: If the contest were in Canada, this method can get you up to four repetitions: rot13(n n n, ru?) :-)

Comment: @JeremyDover [see also](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/10730/5373)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Nice! In hindsight, I realize I may have inadvertently caused offense in attempting a joke...apologies if so.

Comment: naw, youre good :)

Comment: This is the intended answer, but there are so many other equally legit answers given that I'm a bit embarrassed for not considering all of the possibilities when I devised this puzzle.

Comment: If this spelling bee were taking place in a French or Spanish (likely others) speaking country, and we used the Hawaiian word rot13(nn), you'd have the letter repeated SIX times: rot13(nn. n n.  nn).  (Doesn't work in English because that's not how we pronounce that letter, but in many other languages it does.)

Answer (score 24):

The word could be something like

> ESSENTIALNESS, where the speller would say:
>
>  "Essentialness. E-S-S-E-N-T-I-A-L-N-E-**S-S. Ess**entialness".

Some other possibilities

> given by [Qat](https://quinapalus.com/cgi-bin/qat?pat=es*ss&ent=Search&dict=0) for this pattern are "escapeless" and "estrangedness". (It's possible that other letters give other words that work as well, but S was the easiest to find.)

Comment: Another possibility: "Evictee. E-V-I-C-T-E-E, evictee."

Answer (score 20):

I think the intended answer might be:

> Wuumu - a dialect of the Fuumu language. When spelled, one would say "double you you you em you". An alternative of this is "Iwuumu", which might be the alternative answer.

That said, I think Rand's and Deus's answers are better and more creative.

Comment: Ah, I meant to look for rot13(jbeqf pbagnvavat JHH) for my answer, but somehow forgot that possibility while checking the others. +1.

Answer (score 16):

The word...

> Ess

... is in the [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ess).

Following the spelling-bee rule that one must repeat the word after it has been spelt, she would have to say

> E-S-S. Ess.

Which would sound like...

> S - S - S.

Another dictionary word where this would work is:

> "Ell" - a measurement of length. Thanks to @JeremyDover for pointing this out.

Comment: rot13(RYY) would work by this same logic.

Answer (score 14):

One possibility is

> [secco](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/secco)

because the speller would have said

> "e**s ee see see** oh" (emphasis mine - sounds like CCC).

---

Another possibility is

> [squush](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/squush)

because the speller would have said

> "ess k**yoo yoo yoo** ess aitch" (emphasis mine - sounds like UUU).

---

Another possibility, which only works in certain types of English:

> [enzedder](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Enzedder),

because the speller would have said

> "en ze**d ee dee dee** ee ar" (emphasis mine - sounds like DDD). This works in British English but not in American English - I don't know about other types of English such as New Zealand English.

Comment: Interesting! We both came at this from different angles. I like your answer, too.

Comment: @Deusovi Indeed! Yours is a bit more lateral, I think, as it involves more than just spelling the word. But interesting to see different ideas.

Comment: "Bee" would work for this one too, and it's in the title three times! (Probably just coincidence, but still.)

Answer (score 7):

Although this already has an accepted answer, a word which could give a similar effect is

> eerie (*adjective*, strange and frightening)

This is due to the manner in which the word is pronounced - that is to say

> When you hear "eerie", you 'ear "e" at the end

So, the contestant's answer would be

> Eerie.  E, E, R, I, E.  Eerie.

Or, phonetically:

> Ear-**Ee.  Ee, Ee**, Are, Eye, Ee.  Ear-Ee

Answer (score 4):

Alternative answer

> I don't know how often this comes up in a spelling bee but if the word is a compound word and one or other parts of the word are themselves part of an open compound, this justifies the use of the "en dash" in the compound word.
>  For example, in the phrase "pre-Islamic jinn–worshipper", the "dash" in "jinn–worshipper" can be justified to be an "en dash". I know that contestants in spelling bees often ask for words to be used in a sentence so this would clarify the form of the word.
>  In this case, when asked to spell the word **JINN–WORSHIPPER** it would read
>  jay, aye, **en, en, en** dash, double u, o, or, es, aitch, aye, pee, pee, ee, or
>  and thus sounds like three **en**s repeated in a row.